# VS2015 Community Edition Keeps Adding Unwanted <> to my Linq Methods

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I need help finding a setting is VS 2015 Community Edition. When I create a LINQ statement, usually after Selecting an anonymous object (but not every time I do it), if I call another LINQ method (like ToList or Where), VS *very* unhelpfully sticks empty <> between the method name and the parenthesis.

NOTE: This also happens on the professional edition of VS at work.

Here's an example. I typed everything except the final <> in ToList<>(). The angle brackets are popped in as soon as I type the opening parens.

```
var things = report.ReportItems
            .Select( item => new
            {
                a = item.PropA,
                b = item.PropB
            } )
            .ToList<>();
```

It's getting frustrating. Does anyone know how to stop this?

**EDIT:2017/04/08**

Further information: it seems to happen ONLY after I .Select a new anonymous object (although not after EVERY anonymous object, but it seems like it's happening more and more frequently).

I have also noticed that if I press ENTER or TAB (while intellisense has my method selected), then this will *not* happen. However, I press SPACE, or OPEN-PARENS, then it *does* happen.

Comment: Are you, by chance, using any visual studio plugins? I've tried reproducing your issue with no success.

Comment: @JohnStrit I don't think so. There are some extensions like Xamarin, some Azure things, and NuGet, but I'm not using anything like CodeMaid or ReSharper. I loaded VS on this computer just a few weeks ago, so anything in it is out-of-the-box.

Comment: Having a similar issue. I recently installed the "Productivity Power Tools" extension. I turned off everything in the settings other than "Custom Document Well" since that's all I'm using and it seemed to fix it. I can't reproduce the issue now though, even if I turn everything back on.

Comment: Hi @miked. Did you experience this issue before or after you installed "Productivity Power Tools"? I do not have this extension installed, but I am downloading it now to see if I can replicate your results. BTW, I have determined that this happens with EVERY .Select that returns an anonymous type.